# How to build a mixed Java/Scala project?

Tags: java, scala, build

I have the source files for a third-party open source project with the file structure `./src/main/java/*` and  `./src/main/scala/*` with .java and .scala files inside respectively. There are no other files there (i.e., no build.xml or pom.xml), and I have very little knowledge about how it is supposed to work. How do I compile this project?

P.S. I have some experience with Java, but I have never worked with Scala, let alone the mixed projects.

Comment: did you know about sbt? http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/index.html

Comment: @j-keck I didn't know about sbt. How is it useful here? There are no .sbt files either.

Comment: Your question seems quite broad. At least for me.

Comment: @trejder how can I make it more precise? could you give me an example of the details that would help you to answer the question? thanks.

Comment: I can't give you more details, because I'm not a Java developer. But your question seems to broad and can attract many opinion-based or equally broad answers. This site is generally for asking precise questions and getting precise answer. Not for asking about basics or wide problems. Even though I'm not Java developer, I can clearly see, that your answer asks about quite basics and that it can attract many wide answers. This site isn't for guessing or is not acting like a forum. Sorry, that I can't help more. I'm just trying to explain, why others are downvoting your question.

Comment: @trejder I appreciate that. Do you you know any other place more appropriate for such a basic question? I have googled this for an hour and I haven't found anything, so that's why I posted it here.

Comment: Nope, sorry, I don't know. For basic knowledge in my languages, I usually ask Uncle Google. That usually works, so I'm quite off ideas, what to do, when this fails. Sorry.

Comment: You've told us next to nothing about this project, so I can't imagine how anyone here would have any idea how to build it. How about starting by mentioning what project it is, so we can just go look at it?

Comment: If there is a "project/" directory then that contains an SBT configuration and it uses SBT. I don't know how e.g. gradle is configured. If it's an open-source project there are likely to be public installation instructions. If you need to write your own configuration it can be fairly simple if the layout is standard - I recommend maven with the maven scala plugin - but you would need to figure out all the dependencies in that case and it seems unlikely there isn't a build system set up already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this by adding the sources to a new project in IntelliJ IDEA.

Turns out, it has build-in functionality for multi-language development and is able to understand all the cross-language imports between Scala code and Java code. All I had to do is to look at the compile errors to deduce the external dependencies and download the proper libraries from the Internet.

Hope this helps some other clueless person like me.

P.S. I haven't provided any more details about the project, because there are no other details. It was just .java and .scala source files. Nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you want to build the project. Gradle? Eclipse?

In Gradle you modify the build.gradle file. Import the Java and the Scala plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'scala'
```

And add dependencies (I won't write how to do that). You might also want to make sure it compiles Java and Scala together during the Scala compilation phase if they are cross-dependent:

```
sourceSets.main.scala.srcDir "src/main/java"
sourceSets.test.scala.srcDir "src/test/java"
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []
sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = []
```

In Eclipse you need to download the Scala IDE and create a Scala project. It should work without needing much else.

... other build tools work of course too...